# AutoComplete do Primefaces não passa value para o bean

Tags: java, primefaces, autocompletar, value

Estou com um problema com o componente autoComplete do PrimeFaces. O parâmetro value não está sendo passado para o meu bean.

```
private String filtroClientes;

public List<String> listarFiltroDeClientes()
{
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Cliente> clientesFiltrados = Clientes.buscarPorPartesDoNome(filtroClientes);


    for(int  i = 0; i < clientesFiltrados.size(); i++)
    {
        lista.add(clientesFiltrados.get(i).getNomeCliente());
    }

    return lista;

}

public String getFiltroClientes() {
    return filtroClientes;
}

public void setFiltroClientes(String filtroClientes) {
    this.filtroClientes = filtroClientes;
}
```

```html
<p:autoComplete id="acCliente" value="#{projetosBean.filtroClientes}" 
       completeMethod="#{projetosBean.listarFiltroDeClientes()}"/>
```

Ao dar um print no "filtroClientes" ele mostra o valor null, ou seja o que foi digitado no input do autoComplete não está passando para o bean. Fora isso o componente está funcionando normalmente, já testei passar uma string qualquer para filtrar os clientes e o componente funcionou.

Quem puder ajudar desde já agradeço. Valeu!!

Comment: criou um método get para filtroClientes ?

Comment: Sim criei os métodos, o interessante que se eu inicio a variável com algum valor, ele pega aquele valor mais não atualiza ele, ou seja o get funciona o set não.

Comment: Você chegou a ver o exemplo la no showcase do prime? eu não tenho mais utilizado JSF mas em todos exemplos que vi ele recebem no método listarFiltroDeClientes() uma query String ex: listarFiltroDeClientes(String query) para concatenar com o nome ex: lista.add(query + clientesFiltrados.get(i).getNomeCliente());
Um outro detalhe é que eles não usam construtor na EL ex: completeMethod="#{projetosBean.listarFiltroDeClientes}" veja: [Auto Complete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml)

Comment: Qual o Scopo do seu managerbean ? Veja se esta com ViewScope.

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no completeMethod:

```
<p:autoComplete id="acCliente" value="#{projetosBean.filtroClientes}" 
                        completeMethod="#{projetosBean.listarFiltroDeClientes()}"/>
```

Não se usa o "()" chamando métodos do mbean. Mude para:

```
<p:autoComplete id="acCliente" value="#{projetosBean.filtroClientes}" 
                        completeMethod="#{projetosBean.listarFiltroDeClientes}"/>
```

Da forma que estava teu método de autocompletar nem era chamado, por isso o valor não era setado no value. Com essa mudança deve funcionar.